# Ext.define атрибуты uses, loader

Tags: javascript, extjs

Привет.

Подскажите, как использовать эти атрибуты. Просьба подкрепить слова примером. 
Ссылка на полезную статью:
http://metanit.com/web/extjs/2.1.php

**loader**: загружает все другие необходимые классы и зависимости, если таковые не имеются, данный этап пропускается.

**uses**: импортирует классы, которые будут использоваться вместе с новым классом.